# Subtract value from previous row in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have table with the following structure

```
ID  VALUE
1   100
2   200
3   300
4   400
5   500
```

I want output like this

```
ID  VALUE  DIFF_to_Prev
1   100     0
2   200    100 
3   300    100 
4   400    100
5   500    100
```

This is the query I've tried so far

```
SET @LastVALUE:= 0;
SET @LastSN:= 0;

SELECT dtr.SN, dtr.VALUE, 
       IF(@LastSN = dtr.SN, dtr.Value - @LastVALUE, 0) DIFF_to_Prev     
    FROM difftworows as dtr
```

This is the results I get from it:

```
ID      VALUE   DIFF_to_Prev
1       100     0
2       200     0
3       300     0
4       400     0
5       500     0
```

I want to know what I'm doing wrong. Please tell me how can I fix it with suggestions.

Thanks!!

Comment: You have a couple of issues. You do not order the values so MySQL is free to return and process them in any order. But the big issue is that you do not assign the previous value to _@LastVALUE_ when you process each row so it will remain set to 0. Further there is no reason to store or compare the previous value of SN (ie, _@LastSN_ )

Answer (score 6):

Of course you a getting 0 in this column, you are not giving the parameter any value..

If the ID's are continuously and 3 will always be previous of 4 , and 4 of 5 and ETC... then it can be done with a join:

```
SELECT t.id,t.value,t.value-coalese(s.value,0) as DIFF_to_Prev
FROM YourTable t
LEFT OUTER JOIN YourTable s ON(t.id = s.id + 1)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this solution sagi. But could you please help me in giving some suggestion in my query.  I want this to be done by variable. :)

Comment: Isnt it supposed to be `s.id - 1` ?

Comment: Sry, but I'm not good with mysql syntax's with variables:) @Enissay no, we want to connect a row to the row with id-1 ,for example - that means connect T.id(5) to s.id(4) , so s.id+1 will be 5

Comment: Oh, it's `s.id = t.id -1`... My bad xD  But still, for the 1st row, you'll have `t.value - 0` which wont result in `0` as requested... If I'm not mistaken xD

Comment: Yea I saw that, but I assumed he made a mistake with the example since the definition of this column is value-last value , that in those case results in value. @Enissay

Answer (score 5):

E.g.:

```
SELECT x.*
     , COALESCE(x.value-@prev,0) diff_to_prev
     , @prev:=value  
  FROM my_table x
     , (SELECT @prev:=null) vars 
 ORDER 
    BY id;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SET @LastVALUE:= 0;
SELECT dtr.ID, dtr.VALUE, 
    0 - @LastVALUE + (@LastVALUE := dtr.VALUE) DIFF_to_Prev     
FROM difftworows as dtr
ORDER BY dtr.ID
```

If first Diff really needs to be 0:

```
SET @LastVALUE:= NULL;
SELECT dtr.ID, dtr.VALUE,
  CASE 
    WHEN @LastVALUE IS NULL THEN 0 * (@LastVALUE := dtr.VALUE)
    ELSE 0 - @LastVALUE + (@LastVALUE := dtr.VALUE)
  END DIFF_to_Prev
FROM difftworows as dtr
ORDER BY dtr.ID
```

Answer (score 2):

I'll revive it, as now there is way better way to do it - in mysql 8+ there are window functions for such a problems. For this situation you could use lag, like here:
https://learnsql.com/blog/difference-between-two-rows-in-sql/

For you itd be:

```
VALUE - LAG(VALUE) OVER (ORDER BY ID ) AS DIFF_to_Prev
```

Answer (score 1):

Without using user variables

```
SELECT sub0.ID, 
        sub0.VALUE,
        sub0.VALUE - (COALESCE(d2a.VALUE, sub0.VALUE)) AS DIFF_to_Prev
FROM
(
    SELECT d1.ID, d1.VALUE, MAX(d2.ID) AS d2_max_id
    FROM difftworows d1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN difftworows d2
    ON d1.ID > d2.ID
    GROUP BY d1.ID, d1.VALUE
) sub0
LEFT OUTER JOIN difftworows d2a
ON sub0.d2_max_id = d2a.ID
ORDER BY sub0.ID
```

EDIT - avoiding the sub query:-

```
SELECT d1.ID, 
        d1.VALUE,
        d1.VALUE - IF(COUNT(d2.ID) = 0, d1.VALUE, SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(d2.VALUE ORDER BY d2.ID DESC), ',', 1)) AS DIFF_to_Prev
FROM difftworows d1
LEFT OUTER JOIN difftworows d2
ON d1.ID > d2.ID
GROUP BY d1.ID, 
        d1.VALUE
```

Comment: First sub query gets each row from difftworows and the ID of the previous row (ie, highest id that is less than that rows id). That result is then joined against difftworows to get the other details from the previous row to subtract the value.

Comment: Yes but it can be done with at least half of what you did here

Comment: Not easily. I have a solution that avoids the sub query but relies on tricks with GROUP_CONCAT.

Comment: @sagi - your solution only works if there are no gaps in the range of ids.

Comment: BTW you second solution won't work.. you are joining where d1.id > d2.id .. what you need is id > id+1 . In your solution 5 will be joined to 4,3,2 and 1 which is supposed to join only to 4 . You can use rownum to give a number and then connect the next one incase there are gaps

Comment: @sagi - it does work, and I have tested it. Works by doing a join to get all the values concatenated together order by the ID descending, then uses SUBSTRING_INDEX to just get the first value (ie, the one from the highest ID less than the current ID).